# Submit button is not working in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I don't have experience in Selenium. I have tried a couple of things to click a submit button inside a form but nothing is working for me. Please help me out to solve this problem.

I found that the button is enabled (`is_enabled()`), but not displayed (`is_displayed()`).

I tried the following options one by one. I have added the consecutive result of that code in the comment.

```
z=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='commit']")
z.click() #It is showing error, Message: element not interactable
z.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) #It is showing error, Message: element not interactable
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", z) #Shows no error, but nothing happens
z.submit() #Shows no error, but nothing happens
```

I tried with `driver.implicitly_wait(20)` but no luck.
I tried with until option too but it gives error.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='commit']"))).submit() #This raises TimeoutException
```

The HTML code is following

```
input type="submit" name="commit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off" data-disable-with="Calculate"
```

The webpage link is : https://proteins.plus/ktypdbdd9c38b7-1738-45fd-a0fb-90ea86f5dd8b
I clicked on "DoGSiteScorer Binding site detection", then "DoGSiteScorer" button. Now I want to lick the "Calculate" button which is not working.

How should I do it then?

Comment: `z.submit` works if z is a form, is it ? can you show the HTML ?

Comment: Show more HTML, please. Also if you can just send a link. Is the button not visible until something else is completed or what is it that you are waiting on for the button to become visible?

Comment: The webpage link is : https://proteins.plus/ktypdbdd9c38b7-1738-45fd-a0fb-90ea86f5dd8b I clicked on "DoGSiteScorer Binding site detection", then "DoGSiteScorer" button. Now I want to lick the "Calculate" button which is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
z=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='commit']")
```

returns 11 elements on that page, and you can't call `click()` on 11 elements.

Assuming you want to click the red Calculate button, try this:

```
z = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@name='commit'])[2]")
z.click()
```

Comment: I didn't realize that! It works just fine. I am now in the next step. Thank you so much.